# Having java.lang.NullPointerException with MlKitContext

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to implement ML Kit Context to recognize text.
Here is my code

```
private val textRecognition = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS)
private fun recognizeText(imageUri: Uri) {
    try {
        val inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(requireContext(), imageUri)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            textRecognition.process(inputImage).addOnSuccessListener {
                viewBinding.wordEt.text = it.text
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                it.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

I have this error when launching my app

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: MlKitContext has not been initialized
```

So, I tried to add MLKit.initialize() into Application.onCreate(), however, I still have an error.

```
class TranslateApplication : Application() {
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    FavoriteRepository.initialize(this)
    MlKit.initialize(this)
}
```

}

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.mlkit.vision.text.TextRecognizer com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.zzm.zza(com.google.mlkit.vision.text.TextRecognizerOptionsInterface)' on a null object reference
```

Any advice or insight would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

[reference here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/common/MlKit)

Add to AndroidManifest.xml and disable contect provider.
Dont forget change applicationId like com.example.appname

```
<provider
   android:name="com.google.mlkit.common.internal.MlKitInitProvider"
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.mlkitinitprovider"
   tools:node="remove" />
```

Now, call MlKit.initialize in try-catch block in application class.

```
        try {
        MlKit.initialize(this)
    }catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("MainApp", e.message.toString())
    }
    val options = GmsBarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
        //.enableAutoZoom()
        .allowManualInput()
        .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_ALL_FORMATS)
        .build()

    val gmsBarcodeScanning = GmsBarcodeScanning.getClient(this, options)

    val moduleInstall = ModuleInstall.getClient(this)
    val moduleInstallRequest = ModuleInstallRequest.newBuilder()
        .addApi(gmsBarcodeScanning)
        .build()
    moduleInstall
        .installModules(moduleInstallRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            if (it.areModulesAlreadyInstalled()) {
                // Modules are already installed when the request is sent.
                Log.v("GmsBarcodeScanning", "AlreadyInstalled")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.e("onCreate", it.message.toString())
        }
```

It's work for me.